# Cartesian tensors/change of basis/rotation - Dot product geometric issue

Tags: notation, vectors, tensors

I was hoping someone could help with the following:

[Working in index notation]

I understand that we can write a new basis e'_i = (a_ij)(e_j) , where e'_i is the new basis, a_ij is the rotation (change of basis) , and e_j is the old basis.

I found something in my lectures notes I do not understand....

"The dot product of e'_i and e_k = a_ik , clearly, a_ik is the component of e'_i in the e_k direction. *****Also, a_ik can be considered as the component of e_k in the e'_i direction*****"

I understand why l_ik is the component of e'_i in the e_k direction, purely since e'_i = a_ik (e_k) ... which makes sense, but I don't understand why it's the other way around?

At this stage we haven't yet shown A is orthogonal , so please do not use the fact that we can just use the transpose.

Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: MathJax 101: to get $e'_1 = a_{ij}e_j$ type `$e'_1 = a_{ij}e_j$`.  Or if you'd prefer ${e_1}'$ or $e_{1'}$ type `${e_1}'$` or `$e_{1'}$`, respectively.  If you'd like to signify which things are vectors and which aren't you could get any of the following $\{ \mathbf e_1, \vec e_1, \hat e_1 \}$ by typing `$\{ \mathbf e_1, \vec e_1, \hat e_1 \}$`.  To get the dot product $a\cdot b = \langle a, b \rangle$ type `$a\cdot b = \langle a, b \rangle$`.  For more info, see [this tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: No, --------.             .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expand ${e_i}'$ in the basis $\{ e_1, \dots, e_n\}$.

$${e_i}' = a_{i1}e_1 + a_{i2}e_2 + \cdots + a_{ij}e_j + \cdots + a_{in}e_n$$

Taking the dot product with $e_j$ yields

$$\begin{align}e_j\cdot {e_i}' &= e_j \cdot(a_{i1}e_1 + a_{i2}e_2 + \cdots + a_{ij}e_j + \cdot + a_{in}e_n) \\ &= a_{i1}(e_j\cdot e_1) + \cdots + a_{in}(e_j\cdot e_n) \\ &= a_{i1}(0) + \cdots a_{i(j-1)}(0) + a_{ij}(1) + a_{i(j+1)}(0) + \cdots a_{in}(0) \\ &= a_{ij}\end{align}$$

Thus $a_{ij}$ is the component ${e_i}'$ in the $e_j$ direction.

---

Now because $\{{e_1}', \dots, {e_n}'\}$ is a basis for the space also, we can expand $e_j$ in them: $$e_j = b_{1j}{e_1}' + b_{2j}{e_2}' + \cdots + b_{ij}{e_i}' + \cdots + b_{nj}{e_n}'$$ and take the dot product with ${e_i}'$.  After the same steps as above you'll get ${e_i}'\cdot e_j = b_{ij}$.  But because ${e_i}'\cdot e_j = e_j \cdot {e_i}'$, and we already found $e_j \cdot {e_i}' = a_{ij}$, that means that $b_{ij}=a_{ij}$.  What can you conclude from here?

---

BTW, this only works because $\{e_1, \dots, e_n\}$ and $\{{e_1}', \dots, {e_n}'\}$ are *orthonormal* bases.  If they were general bases you'd have to take the dot product with an element of the dual basis ($e^j$ or ${e^i}'$). Pretty fun, right?  ;)

Comment: What I want to know is "Why can a_ik be considered as the component of e_k in the e'_i direction?" .....

Comment: Even if you replace that last line with $e_j = b_{1j}{e_1}' + b_{2j}{e_2}' + \cdots + b_{ij}{e_i}' + \cdots + b_{nj}{e_n}'$, it really doesn't matter.  Your next step is to take the dot product with ${e_i}'$ which'll zero all of the components *except* the one on ${e_i}'$.  But we know that $e_j\cdot {e_i}'$ must equal ${e_i}'\cdot e_j$ (because the dot product is symmetric), thus from the work above that $b_{ij}=a_{ij}$.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Well it does matter , because the fact is this cannot be assumed, you cannot write e_j in terms of the new basis, because at this stage in the text you do not know what e_j is in terms of the new basis [Obviously from Linear algebra you do know what this is]....

Comment: I'm not assuming I know what the values of $\{b_{ij}\}$ *are*.  I'm only using the fact that there must be an expansion of $e_j$ in terms of the basis $\{{e_i}'\}$, because that's what the word *basis* means -- that we can expand *any* vector in the space in them.

Comment: Arriving at e'_i dot e_j = a_ij isnt the problem here... I understand how to get there, I'm saying why does , purely, the statement " e'_i dot e_j = a_ij" alone tell you that  a_ik be considered as the component of e_k in the e'_i direction?

Comment: Are you asking what "the component in the ${e_i}'$ direction" means?

Comment: So have you figured it out now?

Comment: ${e_i}'\cdot e_j=a_{ij}$ tells us that the component of $e_j$ in the ${e_i}'$ direction is $a_{ij}$ -- that's the whole point of the dot product: to tell us the components of a vector in a certain direction.  It also tells us that the component of ${e_i}'$ in the $e_j$ direction is $a_{ij}$ (which can be seen after working through the steps I did above).  $j$ is just an arbitrary letter, so the above also holds if we replace all the $j$'s with $k$'s.

Comment: Sorry about that, I mixed up the indices ! Please see the edit:)!

Comment: $a_{ij}$ is NOT the component of $\mathbf {e_k}$ in the ${e_i}'$ direction.  It is the component of $\mathbf {e_j}$ in the ${e_i}'$ direction.  If your notes have an $e_k$ there, then it's just a typo.

Comment: I know, I know! It's not a typo, its me being an idiot... What you've just said there, about it being the component of e_j in the e'_i direction, how do you know that?

Comment: The component of a vector $v$ in the direction of another vector $w$ *means* the norm of the projection of $v$ onto the subspace $\operatorname{span}(w)$.  From linear algebra we know that the norm of the projection of $v$ onto $\operatorname{span}(w)$ is given by $\dfrac{v\cdot w}{\|w\|}$.  So the component of $e_j$ in the direction of ${e_i}'$ is **defined** as $\dfrac{e_j \cdot {e_i}'}{\|{e_i}'\|}$, where $\|{e_i}'\|=1$ because it is part of an *orthonormal* basis.  Thus the component of $e_j$ in the direction of ${e_i}'$ is $\color{red}{e_j \cdot {e_i}'}$.

Comment: There's nothing really to prove here.  This is just the *definition* of the "component of a vector in the direction of another vector".

Comment: Yesss my man! :P So , concluding question : :                                               is it legit to say that since e_j dot e'_i = e'_i dot e_j = a_ij is  "the component of e'_i in the direction e_j ", and also that " it is the component of e_j in the direction e'_i? Thanks a lot for the help, much appreciated!

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: I assume looking at the defn above, since their both of unit length they both mean the same thing... thank you for providing the proper defn !

Comment: No problem. :-)